# Can vim handle unicode line and paragraph separators?

Tags: unicode

Line endings differ between platforms; LF on unix, CRLF on windows, CR on Mac OS Classic. Unicode introduced LS (Line separator, U+2028) and PS (Paragraph separator, U+2029), as unambiguous alternatives to platform-defined line endings.

Vim can handle LF, CR, or CRLF line endings just fine. Can it be configured to do the Right Thing with the Unicode separators as well?

(context: natural-language text, not programming)